# brew bundle command takes long time to install upon updating the Brewfile

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

`brew bundle` command takes really long time to install updated `Brewfile`. I have added a `sourcetree` to `Brewfile`

```
cask 'sourcetree'
```

and then run the command `brew bundle`. It took really long time to complete installation.

**Homebrew version: Homebrew 1.5.4**

Does anyone experience this behaviors from Brew?

Comment: Having similar behavior as you are!